# Can I remap SHIFT+CAPS LOCK in Linux console?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, console, keyboard-layout, netbook

I recently acquired an old netbook which has no backslash/pipe key. I have successfully remapped the caps lock to backslash using `loadkeys`.
I would like to map <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> to the pipe key in a similar way, in particular not using anything like `xkb` as I want all this to work on my VTs.

Is it possible to do this using `loadkeys` or some other tool?

Comment: I haven't done it before, but [this][1] looks quite encouraging.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177953/how-to-bind-key-to-another-key-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can see xmodmap is part of Xorg and will only work within X. I am looking for something to remap keys within a VT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my own answer in the `keymaps` man page. On my keyboard the <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> has keycode 41. To remap it, you need the following keymap line,

```
keycode 41 = backslash bar
```

This will map <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> to the backslash character, and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> to the bar (pipe) character.

Comment: In what file should that line be put?

Comment: It's a while since I did this so I don't really remember. But check out `man keymaps`, `man dumpkeys` and `man loadkeys`. I think you need to dump the kernel keycode translation tables with `dumpkeys`, add or update the keymap with the line I gave in the original answer and then use `loadkeys` to load these keymaps. But, as I said, I may not quite be remembering correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XKB options on the console.  See `keyboard(5)`.

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"
```

in `/etc/default/keyboard` will make the key to the left of <kbd>A</kbd> [behave the way it should](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_lock#Caps_Lock_versus_Control_key) in X and on text VTs.

Apparently you can use a `KMAP=file` option in `/etc/default/keyboard`, to support arbitrary remappings.  This would be where you could put `keycode 41 = backslash bar`, I think.

Run `setupcon` to apply the change on a text VT.