# How do I remap caps lock to esc key in dwm?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dwm

The question title pretty much says it all... I am trying to remap the CAPS LOCK key to ESC using the dwm window manager. I am using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Welcome to SE ! Please, edit your post with the correct Ubuntu release version. I don't think `ubuntu 20` is a thing. Even though the post deals with VT, would https://www.unix.stackexchange.com/q/180283/72707 help ?

Comment: This has been answered at [How to map the Caps Lock key to Escape key in Arch Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/566871/how-to-map-the-caps-lock-key-to-escape-key-in-arch-linux).

Comment: Devon, the post you directed me to was just what I needed. I ended up using the `setxkbmap -option caps:escape` command. Is there a way to execute this command on system startup using dwm as my window manager?

Comment: Cbhihe, I edited the question as you asked. I indeed discovered that Ubuntu 20 does not yet exist...

Comment: @Dincio Put the command in `~/.xinirc` if you start dwm with startx or in `~/.xprofile` if you use a display manager. You can read about [Autostarting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting) on the ArchWiki.

Comment: @Devon putting it in `~/.xprofile` did the trick. Thank you for your time.

Comment: FWIW, this has nothing to do with the window manager.

Answer (score 2):

Just put
`setxkbmap -option caps:escape`
into your xinitrc, or find another way to call that command at boot.

It's what I do, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

A more clean option is to use `xorg-xmodmap`

To change key:

```
xmodmap -e "clear Lock" -e "keycode 0x42 = Escape"
```

Save the content

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmap
```

Automatically load xmodmap settings on start: (in your `.xinitrc`)

```
 if [ -f ~/.xmodmap ]; then
     xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
 fi
```